# Perl Regular expression to replace the last matching string after dot

Tags: regex, perl

I have string `$someString = "XXX.v2016.12.016"`. Now I am trying to replace the last three digits (after dot) by incrementing one (output: `"XXX.v2016.12.017"`). Does anyone have idea how to do this with regex?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @melpomene  So _many_ of those ... I just vote to close (at least, and perhaps with a comment)

Comment: @zdim I decided to write an answer because the string increment trick may not be immediately obvious.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has two parts: Matching the digits after the last dot, and replacing/incrementing them.

It's possible to do this with [`s///`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer):

```
$someString =~ s{\.([0-9]+)\z}{
    my $n = $1;
    "." . ++$n
}e;
```

The regex matches a dot, followed by 1 or more digits, followed by the end of the string. This takes care of matching the last digit group.

The replacement part of a substitution normally behaves like a double-quoted string, but with the `e` flag it turns into a block of code.

We assign the captured group of digits (`$1`) to a temporary variable, `$n`. This is because we want to use the increment operator `++` on it, not just add `1`. The `++` operator is a bit special in that it handles strings: For numeric strings it preserves leading zeroes, for example.

The return value of the replacement block is a string consisting of a `.` (to replace the one we matched), followed by the incremented digit string.

Comment: @ikegami *we want to use the increment operator `++` on it, not just add `1`. [...] For numeric strings it preserves leading digits* ... oops, fixed that to say *leading zeroes*.

Answer (score 1):

```
$someString =~ s{\.([0-9]+)\z}{ sprintf ".%03d", $1 + 1 }e;
```

If you don't want to hardcod the length (maybe because it varies), you can use the following:

```
$someString =~ s{\.([0-9]+)\z}{ sprintf ".%0*d", length($1), $1 + 1 }e;
```

In both cases, you can use `\K` to avoid having to re-add the `.`, but it actually makes the solution slightly longer.

Comment: @zdim, `\d` matches 360 more characters than `[0-9]` unless `/a` is provided (or `/aa` if `/i` is also provided). Despite this, `\d` would surely be fine as well, but it's not my style.